# CSS : My site does not display correctly on Chrome and Safari, but on Firefox it's fine

Tags: css, firefox, browser

There is an error on my website. I want to display my login links at the top of my website but that doesn't work in Google Chrome nor Safari, but it does in Firefox. I believe this has something to do with floating, but adding a clear:both  div before the form does not work.
Lalalalalala is the string I use as temporary replacement for the actual links.

This is the correct display: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wj35.png

This is the wrong display: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQNkI.png

My website is:
www.rajivmanichand.nl

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's good that you've provided pictures of the problem, but it would be even better if you can isolate the problem to a narrow block of code and post it here (and in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) too for extra points).  That way people can see what the problem is more quickly without having to go through all your site's source.

Comment: Not answering someone with a troll face ...

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'm new to StackOverflow. I will add those blocks next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it quite easy to fix the problem you're targeting the wrong element

Add `float:left;` to `img#logo`
and add `clear:both;` to the `nav`

**The css:**

```
img#logo{
display: inline-block;
float: left;
}
div#loginsection {
width: 300px;
height: 44px;
float: right;
display: inline;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
nav {
clear: both;
}
```

that should fix it for ya

don't forget to remove clear both from the `div#loginsection` aswell otherwise it will ignore the `img#logo` float left